# What software can I use to simplify mathematical expressions?

Tags: math-software

I have a relatively long mathematical expression that I would like to further simplify. The problem is that it is too long for the wolfram alpha that I have used so far. Is there another tool (better than wolfram) used among the community for this purpose? I suppose I could use wolfram alpha by putting the expression piece by piece and multiplying it this way. But then to collect everything I'd have to do it by hand - which definitely might not be error proof. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried wolfram Mathematica? There's a whole Stack Exchange site for that: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I also would suggest Mathematica.

Comment: [Wolfram Engine for Developers](https://www.wolfram.com/engine/) is free and will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use sage or maple,sage  has a free tier but the interface is not user friendly,hope this helps,you need to use sage code to do evaluate the expression(simplify it)
Here the website

1. https://sagecell.sagemath.org/
   In my opinion Wolfram Alpha is the best tool out there for a undergraduate like me trying to evaluate complicated expressions
2. You could use wolfram cloud if you like,doesnt time out that fast and shows you the explicit result,but it doesnt show you other things than that,and its free
   Here is the link: https://www.wolframcloud.com/ ,use the basic plan,its free

Comment: Wolfram Cloud appears to be working. Also wanted to try Mathematica but not sure if my uni has the license and it's way too expensive for a student budget.